# Anti spam system laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to prevent users from spamming comments on my site, so I make this before insert, in controller:

```
public function link_comment($id) {
    $spam_checker = DB::table('comments')
    ->whereDate('created_at', today())
    ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->orderby('id', 'desc')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
}
```

So, I want to check if the user send 5 comments within 1 minute, if so send a error. How can I make it?

> Obs: the date is timestamps.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to consider using a service like Akismet to validate comments to see if they are spam.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of controller *use Carbon\Carbon;*

```
  public function link_comment($id) {
        $spam_checker = DB::table('comments')
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1)->toDateTimeString(), Carbon::now()])
        ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->orderby('id', 'desc')
            ->get();
       if(count($spam_checker)>=5){
         //send a error here.
       }
    }
```

Comment: my bad, see the updated answer:  *->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1)->toDateTimeString(), Carbon::now()])*

Comment: Last comment (timestamps): 2018-02-17 14:11:11. Current data (computer): 2018-02-17 14:14:00. Carbon current data return: 2018-02-17 16:10:49... Carbon date is incorrect...

Comment: return Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1)->toDateTimeString();

Comment: whereBetween('created_at', ['2018-02-17 14:19:00', '2018-02-17 14:21:00']) for tests works...

Comment: Check ur utc config and time stored in db

Answer (score 1):

Laravel offers a middleware for this called [ThrottleRequests](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.html).

You can set restrictions based on the number of requests made within a time interval.